# Inflate tree structure C#

Tags: c#, tree

I have a stree structure which i can flatten into an array basically by using:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Flatten()
    {
    return new[] { Value }.Union(_children.SelectMany(x => x.Flatten()));
    }
```

Is there a way to reverse this to restore the tree struture as it was before the "flatten"?

Comment: An IEnumerable has no history so no.

Comment: Ok, would there be some other means of accomplishing this? Essentially i need to transport the tree structure over a protocol which does not support recursive structures (Thrift) and then restore the tree on the other side

Comment: Wrap T in a class that holds Parent (and/or Child) references and transport that?

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is binary-tree here is a simpler solution http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/ otherwise have a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-n-ary-tree/

Comment: The structure basically has to support folders and files. That is, the top level can contain any number of files or sub folders. Sub folders can then again contain any number of files and subfolders and so on and so forth